# Can I stop Drupal from trying to get file size from URLs when saving files?

Tags: files

Saving a Drupal file with an S3 URL results in a watchdog message like this:

> PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for https://s3.amazonaws.com/[…]

This happens because [Drupal 7's `file_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save/7.x) runs `filesize()` unconditionally on every file's URL before saving, and it seems to fail for all URLs even when it is publicly available. I've verified that the file is available using `curl` and I've subsequently verified that `filesize()` still fails, so this is not a timing issue (there are no special characters in the URL):

```
# curl --head https://s3.amazonaws.com/[…]
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[…]
Content-Length: 9008
Server: AmazonS3
# php -a <<< "echo filesize('https://s3.amazonaws.com/[…]');"
[…]
PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for https://s3.amazonaws.com/[…] in php shell code on line 1
```

Is there a way of avoiding such warnings when running `file_save()` *not* involving silencing errors globally?

Comment: Requesting the content length via `filesize` on an S3 stream is perfectly valid: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html. It's not failing because of Drupal's choice of method to get the info, it'll be a server or S3 issue most likely. The `stat` failure indicates the file whose size is being measured doesn't actually exist on S3 at the time of the request, so that might be where to start the debugging. You can't change the use of `filesize` without patching the core function(s) to the best of my knowledge

Comment: To address your edit: _filesize(): stat failed_ literally means that the Amazon API said "no, this file doesn't exist" or "no, you don't have access". It's quite unlikely this is any problem with Drupal, and very likely it's a problem with, say, ACLs, in your S3 config. Trying to address this at the Drupal side would mean either patching the core file functions, patching the S3 module's stream wrapper, or patching core's base stream wrapper class. I can't see any other way, and it wouldn't actually address the underlying issue anyway, it would just mask it

Comment: Why -1? Whether it's a problem with Drupal or not, isn't the problem properly explained and the use case sane?

Comment: I haven't voted, but if it's not a Drupal problem maybe they saw it as "not useful" to a Drupal-specific Q+A site? Difficult to say

Comment: I'd call this a bug - it calls something which isn't needed (the file works fine with a size of 0 in the relevant Drupal table). If the size is needed for other cases, maybe it should be optional, but if it's there "just in case" it should be removed.

Comment: It is required though - it's used to serve the correct content-length header when a private file is downloaded, for example. Also for file size validation, per-user used-space validation. And so on. You can't blame Drupal because your S3 bucket isn't configured correctly - that's the problem you should be trying to fix, not trying to hack around a perfectly reasonable use of a built-in PHP function!

Comment: I don't know why I can't convince you that the bucket is configured just fine - the code is there to prove that `curl` can get the size just fine. I also have over 10000 users with millions of images served through tested code (to the point where we're using Fake S3 for integration tests) who have not complained about any accessibility problems.

Answer (score 0):

Via [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45303338/96588), a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45304474/96588) is to write a custom error handler which ignores only this specific message:

```
function filesize_for_url_ignoring_error_handler($severity, $message, $file, $line, $context) {
    global $originalErrorHandler;
    if (strpos($message, 'filesize(): stat failed for https://') !== 0) {
        $originalErrorHandler($severity, $message, $file, $line, $context);
    }
}

class […] {
    public function […] {
        $originalErrorHandler = set_error_handler('filesize_for_url_ignoring_error_handler');
        $file = file_save($file);
        restore_error_handler();
    }
}
```

Not ideal, but it works.